# OpenGL camera target issue

Tags: c++, opengl, camera, glm-math, direction

I'm implementing a 3D maze game in C++, using OpenGL where the camera is at a fixed position exactly above the middle of the maze looking at the middle too. It works and looks just as I've wanted but the my code is not so nice because I needed to put a `+ 0.01f` into the position to work well. If I miss it out, the labirynth doesn't show up, it seems like the camera points into the opposite direction.. How can I fix it elegantly?

```
glm::vec3 FrontDirection = glm::vec3(((GLfloat)MazeSize / 2) + 0.01f, 0.0f, ((GLfloat)MazeSize / 2)
```

The (0,0,0) origo location is the left corner of the maze (start position) so this is the reason I set the position like this:

```
glm::vec3 CameraPosition = glm::vec3(((GLfloat)MazeSize / 2), ((GLfloat)MazeSize + 5.0f), ((GLfloat)MazeSize / 2))
```

The UpDirection is `(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)` lookAt function looks like this:

```
Matrix = glm::lookAt(CameraPosition, FrontDirection, UpDirection);
```

I know that by convention, in OpenGL the camera points towards the negative z-axis so the FrontDirection is basically pointing in the reverse direction of what it is targeting. For me it would be completely clear to set the positions like I did above but it still is not working as I've expected. (unless I put that `+ 0.01f`)

Thank you for your answer in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that by convention, in OpenGL the camera points towards the negative z-axis

In viewspace the z-axis points out of the viewport, but that is completely  irrelevant. You define the view matrix, the position and the orientation of the camera. The camera position is the first argument of `glm::lookAt`. The camera looks in the direction of the *target*, the 2nd argument of `glm::lookAt`.

The 2nd parameter of [`glm::lookAt`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00247.html#gaa64aa951a0e99136bba9008d2b59c78e) is not a direction vector, it is a point on the line of sight.
Compute a point on the line of sight by `CameraPosition+FrontDirection`:

```cpp
Matrix = glm::lookAt(CameraPosition, CameraPosition+FrontDirection, UpDirection);
```

Your upwards-vector has the same direction as the line of sight. The upwards should be [orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality) to the line of sight. The up-vector defines the *roll*:

```cpp
glm::vec3 CameraPosition = glm::vec3(
    ((GLfloat)MazeSize / 2), ((GLfloat)MazeSize + 5.0f), ((GLfloat)MazeSize / 2));
glm::vec3 CameraTarget = glm::vec3(
    ((GLfloat)MazeSize / 2), 0.0f, ((GLfloat)MazeSize / 2));
glm::vec3 UpDirection = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); 

Matrix = glm::lookAt(CameraPosition, CameraTarget, UpDirection);
```

Comment: I have tried this already and it also does not point where I set....... Also tried to normalize the coordinates but the only and one way I could reach it was the solution above but nahh.. it looks really awful.

Comment: @chuck Your up-vector seems to be wrong, because it points in the same (or exactly opposite) direction as the line of sight. Change from (0, 1, 0) to ((0, 0, 1))

Comment: Thank you man, you saved my life! I changed it to (1, 0, 0) because that's perfect for me. What you mentioned is also nice but I needed a 90 degree rotation. Amazing! Thanks again!!!